# How to create text box dynamically from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create textboxes inside `<div id="screens"> </div>`. I have a drop down menu for which I select the number of textboxes to be created.

The JavaScript code I've written here is not working:

code:

```
function create(param) {
    document.getElementById("screens").innerHTML="";          
    for(var i = 0; i < param; i++) {
        alert(i);
        document.write('<input type="text" name="Fname">');
    }
}
```

This is adding textboxes by clearing all contents of the current page, but I want the textboxes to be added to  `<div id="screen"> </div>`. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read some documentation about [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write). You've used [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) in your code, why not to reuse it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function create(param) {
    var s= "";
    for(var i = 0; i < param; i++) {
        s+= '<input type="text" name="Fname">'; //Create one textbox as HTML
    }
    document.getElementById("screens").innerHTML=s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged jQuery in your question, I'll assuming that you're using jQuery.

```
function create(param) {
    'use strict';

    var i;

    $("#screens").empty();

    for(i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
        $('#screens').append('<input type="text" name="Fname">');
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AppTD/)

A pure JavaScript implementation would look like this:

```
function create(param) {
    'use strict';

    var i, target = document.getElementById('screens');
    target.innerHTML = '';

    for(i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
        target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="Fname">';
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rJPH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function create(param) {
    var screens = document.getElementById('screens'),
        innerHTML = '',
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
        alert(i);
        innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="Fname">';
    }

    screens.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function create(param) {
    var target = document.getElementById('screens'),
        oFrag=document.createDocumentFragment();

    target.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < param; i++) {
        var iptNode = document.createElement("input");
        iptNode.setAttribute("type", "text");
        iptNode.setAttribute("name", "Fname");
        oFrag.appendChild(iptNode);
    }

    target.appendChild(oFrag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var newInput4=document.createElement("input");
newInput4.className="form-control ";
newInput4.name="totalunit"+instance;
newInput4.placeholder="Unit";   
newInput4.type="text";
</script>
```